# Cloud detector s2cloudless run locally is masking non-cloud

Tags: python, rasterio, sentinel-2, cloudmasking

I am trying to use the Cloud-detector on locally stored S2-Images in .SAFE format (L1C). I ran the cloud detector and the cloud mask that is returned comes completely wrong.
Is there something wrong in my code? Or is this a problem with the detection?

This is the code I am running:

```py
       #run s2cloudless
       #initialize s2cloudless
       cloud_detector = S2PixelCloudDetector(threshold=0.4, average_over=4, dilation_size=2)
       print("Resampling bands to 10 meters...")
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B02.jp2") as img:
           B02 = img.read()
           tmparr = np.empty_like(B02)
           aff = img.transform
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B04.jp2") as img:
           B04 = img.read()         
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B08.jp2") as img:
           B08 = img.read()
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B01.jp2") as img:
           B01 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B01, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B01 = tmparr            
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B05.jp2") as img:
           B05 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B05, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B05 = tmparr            
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B8A.jp2") as img:
           B8A = img.read()
           reproject(
               B8A, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B8A = tmparr            
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B09.jp2") as img:
           B09 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B09, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B09 = tmparr              
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B10.jp2") as img:
           B10 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B10, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B10 = tmparr            
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B11.jp2") as img:
           B11 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B11, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B11 = tmparr             
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B12.jp2") as img:
           B12 = img.read()
           reproject(
               B12, tmparr,
               src_transform = img.transform,
               dst_transform = aff,
               src_crs = img.crs,
               dst_crs = img.crs,
               resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
           B12 = tmparr                   
                                                       
       bands = np.array([np.dstack((B01[0]/10000.0,B02[0]/10000.0,B04[0]/10000.0,B05[0]/10000.0,B08[0]/10000.0,B8A[0]/10000.0,B09[0]/10000.0,B10[0]/10000.0,B11[0]/10000.0,B12[0]/10000.0))])
       
       #run s2cloudless
       print("Running s2cloudless..")
       cloud_probs = cloud_detector.get_cloud_probability_maps(bands)
       mask = cloud_detector.get_cloud_masks(bands).astype(rasterio.uint8)
       
       print("Saving cloud mask as raster..")
       #save clouds mask
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_mask}/cloud_mask.tif", "w",  driver='GTiff',height=mask.shape[1],width=mask.shape[2],count=1,dtype=rasterio.uint8,crs=CRS,transform=aff) as dest:
           dest.write(mask)
       with rasterio.open(f"{output_mask}/cloud_probability_mask.tif", "w",  driver='GTiff',height=cloud_probs.shape[1],width=cloud_probs.shape[2],count=1,dtype=cloud_probs.dtype,crs=CRS,transform=aff) as dest:
           dest.write(cloud_probs)
```

The bands shape is `(1, 5210, 7660, 10)` and the mask shape is `(1, 5210, 7660)`.

The image I am showing you below is S2A_MSIL1C_20231004T113321_N0509_R080_T29TNF_20231004T151316.SAFE and I have clipped it around the district of Porto.
This is the RGB composite and the mask cloud for the same image:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Because I was using images [after January 2022](https://documentation.dataspace.copernicus.eu/APIs/SentinelHub/Data/S2L2A.html#harmonize-values) I discovered that the problem was in converting the DNs to reflectance values.While I was dividing my data by 10000.0 I also need to remove from the DN the RADIO_ADD_OFFSET which is equal to 1000 for all bands. So to get reflectance we need to do `(DN - 1000)/10000`. I  also implemented a piece of code to guarantee that there were no negative values since the s2cloudles was not train with those.
I'm going to leave here the final code including how to save the results as rasters in case someone is having the same issue in the future.

```py
        # #initialize s2cloudless
        cloud_detector = S2PixelCloudDetector(threshold=0.4, average_over=4, dilation_size=2)
        scale_factor = 10000.0
        offset = 1000.0
          
        # print("Resampling bands to 10 meters...")
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B02.jp2") as img:
            B02 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            tmparr = np.empty_like(B02)
            aff = img.transform
            B02 = np.clip(B02, a_min=0, a_max=None)
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B04.jp2") as img:
            B04 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            B04 = np.clip(B04, a_min=0, a_max=None)        
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B08.jp2") as img:
            B08 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            B08 = np.clip(B08, a_min=0, a_max=None)
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B01.jp2") as img:
            B01 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B01, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B01 = tmparr
            B01 = np.clip(B01, a_min=0, a_max=None)            
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B05.jp2") as img:
            B05 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B05, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B05 = tmparr 
            B05 = np.clip(B05, a_min=0, a_max=None)           
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B8A.jp2") as img:
            B8A = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B8A, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B8A = tmparr   
            B8A = np.clip(B8A, a_min=0, a_max=None)         
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B09.jp2") as img:
            B09 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B09, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B09 = tmparr       
            B09 = np.clip(B09, a_min=0, a_max=None)       
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B10.jp2") as img:
            B10 =(img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B10, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B10 = tmparr    
            B10 = np.clip(B10, a_min=0, a_max=None)        
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B11.jp2") as img:
            B11 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B11, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B11 = tmparr   
            B11 = np.clip(B11, a_min=0, a_max=None)          
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_clip}/{jp2_name}_B12.jp2") as img:
            B12 = (img.read()-offset)/ scale_factor
            reproject(
                B12, tmparr,
                src_transform = img.transform,
                dst_transform = aff,
                src_crs = img.crs,
                dst_crs = img.crs,
                resampling = Resampling.bilinear)
            B12 = tmparr
            B12 = np.clip(B12, a_min=0, a_max=None)         
                                   
        bands = np.array([np.dstack((B01[0],B02[0],B04[0],B05[0],B08[0],B8A[0],B09[0],B10[0],B11[0],B12[0]))])
        #run s2cloudless
        print("Running s2cloudless..")
        cloud_probs = cloud_detector.get_cloud_probability_maps(bands)
        mask_clouds = cloud_detector.get_cloud_masks(bands).astype(rasterio.uint8)
        
        print(mask_clouds.shape)
        print(cloud_probs.shape)
        
        print("Saving cloud mask as raster..")
        #save clouds mask
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_mask}/cloud_mask.tif", "w",  driver='GTiff',compress="lzw",height=mask_clouds.shape[1],width=mask_clouds.shape[2],count=1,dtype=rasterio.uint8,crs=CRS,transform=aff) as dest:
            dest.write(mask_clouds)
        with rasterio.open(f"{output_mask}/cloud_probability_mask.tif", "w",  driver='GTiff',compress="lzw",height=cloud_probs.shape[1],width=cloud_probs.shape[2],count=1,dtype=cloud_probs.dtype,crs=CRS,transform=aff) as dest:
            dest.write(cloud_probs)
```